# AdGuard Home Hosted in Cloud with Portainer

Tags: docker, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy, portainer

I am running portainer in the cloud with NGINX proxy manager.

I want to accomplish the following

I want to run ADGUARD Home as a docker and make it such that my DNS queries on my devices go through as https request but the nginx proxy manager should correcly route the dns traffic to my adguard portainer and give me the results.

I read this but still have issues implementing this
https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardHome/wiki/Encryption#install

I am trying to do this since i don't want to install a vpn on all my clients or open my port 53 to the entire world

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem over here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csAmd0JxYV4

This was how it was addressed:
Duncan Ross
6 months ago
Great job! Just in case anyone out there has issues with the container deploying saying that port 53 is already in use. The host system (in my case ubuntu) is probably using it. Try this:
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved

This fixed this issue and allowed the container to deploy....happy days.